# GET 404 (Not Found) with fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch, weather-api

I am making a simple weather application using the Weather API and React. But I am having problems when the user enters a non-existent city because despite trying to deal with it, a "GET 404 (Not Found)" still appears on the console.

Fetch code:

```js
if (evt.key === "Enter") {
    fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                res.json().then(result => {
                    setWeather(result);
                    setQuery('');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Erro: ', res);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log('Failure'); });
}
```

Input code:

```
<div className="search-box">
    <input
        type="text"
        className="search-bar"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        value={query}
        onKeyPress={search}
    />
</div>;
```

Console error:

```
GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kdjklsjdl&units=metric&APPID=f3f25e406a03349031cc25ed16a8196d 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: What's the question? The error shows exactly what is expected. Your response code was 404, not 200, so it went into your `else` block. (you should really include console errors as text, not as a picture of text)

Comment: No, for some reason I am not aware of, the 404 error keeps showing up on the console even if it enters else or catch. But I don't want 404 not found to appear on the console, I just want to show something on the screen to the user.

Comment: @Lotus — Debugging tools show that information if the user wants them to. You can't suppress it.

Comment: @Quentin I know, I just want to deal with the error

Comment: @Quentin Well, I read what you mentioned and maybe I have to do that... Thanks

Comment: @Lotus — Deal with the error in the `catch`. Dealing with it is not the same as concealing it from the person using the developer tools though.